# Spark Slow Performance

Tags: python, apache-spark, odbc, parquet, azure-hdinsight

I am working on querying data and then building a visualization on top of it. Currently my whole pipeline works but it can take upwards of 10 minutes sometimes to return the results of my query and I am very sure I am missing some optimization or another crucial step that is causing this slow speed.

Details:
I have about 500gb in 3500 csv’s. I store these in an Azure Blob Storage Account and run a spark cluster on Azure HDInsights. I am using spark 2.1.

Here is the script(PySpark3 on Azure Jupyter Notebook)  I use to ingest the data:

```
csv_df = spark.read.csv('wasb://containername@storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/folder/*.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True)   //Read CSV
csv_df.write.parquet('wasb://containername@storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/folder/parquet_folder/csvdfdata.parquet’) //Write Parquet
parquet_df = spark.read.csv('wasb://containername@storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/folder/parquet_folder/csvdfdata.parquet) //Read Parquet
parquet_df.createOrReplaceTempView(‘temp_table’) //Create a temporary table
spark.sql("create table permenant_table as select * from temp_table"); //Create a permanent table
```

I then use the ODBC Driver and this code to pull data. I understand odbc can slow things a little but I believe 10 minutes is way more than expected.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/hdinsight-dotnet-odbc-spark-sql/blob/master/Program.cs
My code to pull data is similar to this ^

The problem is that the pipeline works but it is way too slow for it to be of any use. The visualizations I create need to pull data in a few seconds at best.

Other details:
A good amount of queries use DateID which has dates in `int format = 20170629` (29th june 2017)
Sample Query = `select DateId, count(PageId) as total from  permanent_table where (DateId >= 20170623) and (DateId <= 20170629) group by DateId order by DateId asc`

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!
Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, one of clarification: What queries are you running from ODBC connection? Is it table creation queries? They would take long time. Make sure you run only read queries from ODBC on a pre-created hive table.

Now assuming you do the above here is few things you can do to make queries run in few seconds.

1. Thrift server on HDI uses dynamic resource allocation. So the first query will take extra time while resources are allocated. After that it should be faster. You can check status of Ambari -> Yarn UI -> Thrift application how much resources it uses - it should use all cores of your cluster.
2. 3500 files is too much. When you create parquet table coalesce(num_partitions) (or repartition) it into smaller number of partitions. Adjust it so there is about 100MB per partition or if there is not enough data - at least one partition per core of your cluster.
3. In your data generation script you can skip one step - instead of creating temp table - directly create hive table in parquet format. Replace `csv_df.write.parquet` with `csv_df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("tablename")`
4. For date queries you can partition your data by year, month, day columns (you will need to extract them first). If you do this you won't need to worry about #2. You may end-up with too many files, if so you would need to reduce partitioning to only year, month.
5. Size of your cluster. For 500GB of text files you should be fine with few nodes of D14v2 (may be 2-4). But depends on complexity of your queries.

Comment: Hi Maxiluk, Thanks for the tips. I partioned by dateId and it gives me a significant boost with speed! for 500gb I am now down to about 2 minutes. Ideally I want to push for a few seconds. any other optimizations I should make to speed up?
Also my final data size would be close to 12TB currently I am using 500GB for testing. Given that what cluster config would you recommend I use? I currently am using a head node of D12 v2 (2 nodes 8 cores) and 4 worker nodes of D4 v2 (4 nodes, 32 cores). What config should I be using?

Comment: Hi, sorry for delay with response. There are many optimizations you can do. I documented most important ones in the Spark performance optimization series of videos here: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Data-Exposed/Spark-Performance-Series-1-with-Maxim-Lukiyanov

Comment: Regarding cluster size for 12TB you would use D14_v2 worker nodes 10-40 of them. With greater number you will get faster speed.